# Create an array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, coordinates

```
MyArray [{latitude: "48", longitude: "2", Destination: "Paris"},{latitude: "18", longitude: "20", Destination: "London"},...etc]
```

I'd like this...

```
MyNewArray [{coordinates: [48,2], Destination: "Paris"},{coordinates: [18,20], Destination: "London"},...etc]
```

My code is something like this...I'd like to create an array in object

```
  var len = MyArray.length;
                 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                {
                        coordinates: MyArray[i].latitude + ', ' + MyArray[i].longitude,
                        lieu: MyArray[i].lieu
                    }
                }
```

Comment: try something like `coordinates: [MyArray[i].latitude, MyArray[i].longitude]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
MyArray = [{latitude: "48", longitude: "2", Destination: "Paris"},{latitude: "18", longitude: "20", Destination: "London"}];

MyNewArray = MyArray.map(function(e)
{
    return {
        coordinates: [+e.latitude, +e.longitude],
        Destination: e.Destination
    };
});

console.log(MyNewArray);
```

`map` will process all elements in the source array, pass them to a function, and return a new array with the return value of each of the function calls.

In the function, we're creating a new object with the requested keys and returning it.

`coordinates` is a new array which contains the coordinates.

I added a `+` in front of each of the coordinates to force conversion to numbers (rather than strings in the original array), this may or may not be required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.map to accomplish the same thing. Check out how it works here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
    MyNewArray = MyArray.map(place => {
     return {
       coordinates: [place.latititude, place.longitude],
       Destination place.Desstination
     };
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED Thanks to eagle eyed commenter below. :-)

```
let newArray = []

MyArray.forEach(item => {
  item.coordinates = [item.latitude, item.longitude]
  newArray.push(item)
})
```

With this, the `MyArray` maintains the same structure whilst your `newArray` variable has been populated with the same Array + a `coordinates` prop for each Object.

Comment: Careful, this will update the items in the original array (`MyArray`).

Comment: This is a misuse of `.map()`. You shouldn't have side effects in a `.map()` callback, especially changing the original array. If you want to modify an array in-place, use `.forEach()` instead of `.map()`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, have amended my example. :-)